# Cómo leer la soap respuesta xml en codeigniter

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, soap

Tengo la siguiente respuesta de webservice al momento de insert data en la base de datos, este me entrega un `recordID`, quiero poder acceder a ese `RecordID` y guardarlo en una variable.

Estoy utilizando codeigniter.

```
$this->load->helper('xml');
    $response = '<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
       <soap:Body>
          <ns1:createDataResponse xmlns:ns1="http://3e.pl/ADInterface">
             <StandardResponse RecordID="1011142" xmlns="http://3e.pl/ADInterface"/>
          </ns1:createDataResponse>
       </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>';
$response = xml_convert($response);
echo $response;
```

he intentado `$xml = simplexml_load_string($response);` pero me obtengo un error.

> Call to undefined function simplexml_load_string()

Answer (score 0):

Pues yo lo hago de esta forma. Una vez tengo la respuesta en una variable, la cargo en un objeto DOMDocument con el método loadXML, como hago a continuación:

```
    //Cargar respuesta en una variable
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadXML($response);
    //Aquí puedes comprobar si la consulta trae algún error (te pongo un ejemplo)
    if($doc->getElementsByTagName('faultcode')->item(0)){
       //Tratamiento del error
       ...
    }else{

        //Ahora ya puedes recorrer los nodos y obtener los valores que quieras. Por ejemplo,
       $this->token = $doc->getElementsByTagName('token')->item(0)->nodeValue;
       ...
    }
```

Espero que te valga, si tienes otra duda me comentas.